# Eclipse: Open Decleration (F3) doesn't open files in Maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

When clicking F3 in Eclipse, the editor jumps to the declaration of the element the cursor was on.

However, this does not work when I try jumping to elements declared in the maven repository:

[image]

In my setup `M2_REPO` is defined under `Window\Preferences\Java\Build Path\Classpath Variables` as "C:\Maven\repository" which is correct.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on the jar in eclipse and clicking 'Maven -> Download Sources'?

Comment: I see all the sources in the jar in the repository

Comment: How right clicking on the project and doing Maven -> Update Project Configuration?

Comment: When I right click on the project I don't have "Maven" as an option. Should I? (I'm using Eclipse SDK 3.6.2 if it matters)

Comment: Have you got the m2eclipse plugin installed?

Comment: no, I'll give it a try, although I don't understand why I would need a plug-in in order for eclipse to be able to open a file at a certain line...